# Automatically suspend VMs after shutdown of Proxmox host

Tags: proxmox

I'm looking for a way to suspend my VMs after the Proxmox host do a restart. Using Hyper-V, its possible to define an action for each VM like suspend or restart, which should be done on the VM after host reboot. Proxmox by default shutdown the VM together with the host. I couldn't find any config option, only to let Proxmox automatically start a VM after shutdown.

I found this article: http://8086.support/content/13/75/en/how-do-i-configure-kvm-to-suspend_restore-virtual-machines-when-the-host-is-rebooted.html Seems exactly what I need, but the file `/etc/sysconfig/libvirt-guests` doesn't exist. This file is part of the `libvirt-client` package, which is not installed and so no part of Proxmox. So I'm not sure, if its a good idea to use Proxmox together with another management solution, which libvirt seems to be. According to [this Entry](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/proxmox-and-libvirt.3813/), its even not possible.

Isn't there a native way from proxmox to suspend a VM after host shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried posting on the Proxmox forums? They're the expert of their product so I'd recommend it.

Even if there's not an easy "built in" way to configure that by default, it's still possible. Proxmox is Debian under the hood, so you could write a script to do what you want on shutdown/reboot.

The builtin `pvesh` allows you to interact with your PVE server from the commandline and do tons of different things (including suspend and start). It interacts with the PVE RESTful API. Info on `pvesh` is [here](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API) and the full API docs are [here](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/api-viewer/index.html).

Once you've written a script that will suspend or restart your VMs, you can then leverage SystemD to launch your script at the appropriate time. E.g. the CLI part of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294539/60506)